# Can I ask this on SO?

Tags: discussion

### Can I ask this on SO? Is it specific enough?  If not, suggestions for what would help?

What are my best options for a Cloud Platform for a site with these parameters?  Why?

1. Rapid and flexible development is a high priority.   Therefore we could trade operational dollars for reduced development expense (within reason).
2. Up to 2000 world wide member users.  These users would upload short videos (~10MB) and other data at least a couple times a day.
3. About 5 main pages that are member accessible which serve mostly Flash content.
4. Up to 100,000 worldwide Facebook fans, accessing the site and viewing a few short videos daily.  10% of this access  will probably be from mobile devices.
5. Primary database tables for “Members” (2000 entries), “Tasks” (3000 entries), and “Uploads” (100000 entries)
6. Only moderate security demands: (No financial transactions, Facebook or OpenID login, low profile target for bot or DDOS threats.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Yuck, not exactly the answer I was looking for.  But I understand the point, and know better than to argue with experts.  I'll see what I get over there.  Thanks.

Comment: -1 for Jeff's reason

Answer (score 3):

It's a shopping recommendation and therefore not suitable for any of our sites IMHO.

Shopping recommendations are not "why" questions that teach, but "what should I buy now?" questions which have negative value over time.

Comment: Another interesting perspective.  I'll own that it could be classified as a "shopping recommendation" and of course it has diminishing (not negative) value over time.  But is that bad?  And does it also mean it doesn't have substantial critical thinking teaching value?  As suggested by original question -- please help me rephrase the question so that it can get at the "Why".  Ultimately that will be more valuable to me than a argumentative poll.

Comment: @mjhm that is impossible in your case -- you have 6 different questions that would have to be presented as 6 different "why" and "teach me how to tell.." requirements. Honestly what you need is a discussion board, this is not at all suited for our (mostly) objective Q&A format.

Comment: I so don't want a discussion board. Signal to noise ratios are way too low to be useful. However I really get what you're saying -- this is definitely not for SO either. I'll hang with the webmasters site for a while to get a better feel for what's appropriate for it's content and spirit before posting.